# My junit tests of my spring project crash ever - Error creating bean with name

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, junit, weblogic

I have many test in my Spring MVC project, my tests worked fine until a few days ago.

Do not know why you stopped working suddenly. Ever than run throws this

> Caught exception while allowing TestExecutionListener
> [org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener@19067e5]
> to prepare test instance
> [com.pak.age.MyTest@1950e0a]
>
> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
> creating bean with name
> 'com.pak.age.MyTest': Injection of
> autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is
> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not
> autowire field: private com.segurosargos.bitacora.api.AsignacionDao
> com.segurosargos.bitacora.cron.ReasignacionTest.asignacionDao; nested
> exception is
> org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No
> matching bean of type [com.pak.age.dao.MyDao]
> found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as
> autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations:
> {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}

This is a template of my tests

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@TestExecutionListeners({ TransactionalTestExecutionListener.class, DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.class })
@ContextConfiguration(locations = { "/testEnviromentContext.xml" })
public class ReaTest {
    
    @Autowired
    private ReaDao reaDao;

    @Test
    public void some(){     
        reaDao.doSome();
    }
}
```

Only tests that containing Autowired references crash, with the same Exception, the strange thing is that before work well.

I am use Spring Tool Suite with EGit (test worked at this), and i use WebLogic, a run project after run tests. Some days ago it worked well.

EDIT:

I do not change `/testEnviromentContext.xml` file, or add DAO or entity class

**EDIT 2:**

This a test

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@TestExecutionListeners({TransactionalTestExecutionListener.class,
    DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.class})
@ContextConfiguration(locations={"/testEnviromentContext.xml"})
public class GrupoDaoImplTest {
    @Autowired
    private GrupoDao grupoDao;
    
    @Test
    public void create(){
        
        Grupo grupo = new Grupo();
        grupo.setNombre("test c "+ Randomizer.getNumSRandom());
        grupo.setDescripcion("test description c "+ Randomizer.getNumSRandom());
        
        grupoDao.toString();
        
        grupoDao.guardar(grupo);
        assertNotNull(grupo.getGrupoID());
    }
    
    @Test
    public void getById(){
            
     Grupo g=grupoDao.getById(1);
     
     assertNotNull(g);
        
    }
    
    @Test
    public void getAll(){
        List<Grupo> grupos = grupoDao.getGrupos();
        assertNotNull(grupos);
        for(Grupo g : grupos)
            System.out.println(g.getNombre()+";");
    }
}
```

This is a complete log

```
ERROR: org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager - Caught exception while allowing TestExecutionListener [org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener@1ce00b4] to prepare test instance [com.segurosargos.bitacora.api.impl.GrupoDaoImplTest@19067e5]
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'com.segurosargos.bitacora.api.impl.GrupoDaoImplTest': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.segurosargos.bitacora.api.GrupoDao com.segurosargos.bitacora.api.impl.GrupoDaoImplTest.grupoDao; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No matching bean of type [com.segurosargos.bitacora.api.GrupoDao] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:287)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1106)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireBeanProperties(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:374)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.injectDependencies(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:110)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:75)
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:321)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.createTest(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:211)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner$1.runReflectiveCall(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:15)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.methodBlock(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:290)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:231)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:50)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:193)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:52)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:191)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:42)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:184)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:236)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:174)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:467)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.segurosargos.bitacora.api.GrupoDao com.segurosargos.bitacora.api.impl.GrupoDaoImplTest.grupoDao; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No matching bean of type [com.segurosargos.bitacora.api.GrupoDao] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:506)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:87)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:284)
    ... 26 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No matching bean of type [com.segurosargos.bitacora.api.GrupoDao] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoSuchBeanDefinitionException(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:924)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:793)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:707)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:478)
    ... 28 more
ERROR: org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager - Caught exception while allowing TestExecutionListener [org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener@1ce00b4] to prepare test instance [com.segurosargos.bitacora.api.impl.GrupoDaoImplTest@e9a7c2]
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'com.segurosargos.bitacora.api.impl.GrupoDaoImplTest': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.segurosargos.bitacora.api.GrupoDao com.segurosargos.bitacora.api.impl.GrupoDaoImplTest.grupoDao; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No matching bean of type [com.segurosargos.bitacora.api.GrupoDao] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:287)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1106)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireBeanProperties(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:374)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.injectDependencies(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:110)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:75)
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:321)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.createTest(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:211)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner$1.runReflectiveCall(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:15)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.methodBlock(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:290)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:231)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:50)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:193)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:52)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:191)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:42)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:184)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:236)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:174)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:467)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.segurosargos.bitacora.api.GrupoDao com.segurosargos.bitacora.api.impl.GrupoDaoImplTest.grupoDao; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No matching bean of type [com.segurosargos.bitacora.api.GrupoDao] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:506)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:87)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:284)
    ... 26 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No matching bean of type [com.segurosargos.bitacora.api.GrupoDao] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoSuchBeanDefinitionException(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:924)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:793)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:707)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:478)
    ... 28 more
ERROR: org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager - Caught exception while allowing TestExecutionListener [org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener@1ce00b4] to prepare test instance [com.segurosargos.bitacora.api.impl.GrupoDaoImplTest@4dd1b]
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'com.segurosargos.bitacora.api.impl.GrupoDaoImplTest': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.segurosargos.bitacora.api.GrupoDao com.segurosargos.bitacora.api.impl.GrupoDaoImplTest.grupoDao; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No matching bean of type [com.segurosargos.bitacora.api.GrupoDao] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:287)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1106)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireBeanProperties(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:374)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.injectDependencies(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:110)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:75)
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:321)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.createTest(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:211)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner$1.runReflectiveCall(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:15)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.methodBlock(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:290)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:231)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:50)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:193)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:52)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:191)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:42)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:184)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:236)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:174)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:467)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.segurosargos.bitacora.api.GrupoDao com.segurosargos.bitacora.api.impl.GrupoDaoImplTest.grupoDao; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No matching bean of type [com.segurosargos.bitacora.api.GrupoDao] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:506)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:87)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:284)
    ... 26 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No matching bean of type [com.segurosargos.bitacora.api.GrupoDao] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoSuchBeanDefinitionException(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:924)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:793)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:707)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:478)
    ... 28 more
```

**EDIT**

testEnviromentContext.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:task="http://www.springframework.org/schema/task"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.1.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/task http://www.springframework.org/schema/task/spring-task-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/util http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-3.1.xsd
        ">
        
    <beans:bean class="org.springframework.mock.web.MockServletContext"/>
    
    <!-- PROPERTIES -->
    <context:annotation-config/>
    <beans:bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
        <beans:property name="locations">
            <beans:list>
                <beans:value>classpath:config.properties</beans:value>
            </beans:list>
        </beans:property>
        <beans:property name="ignoreUnresolvablePlaceholders" value="true" />
    </beans:bean>
    <beans:bean id="messageSource" class="org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource">
        <beans:property name="basenames">
            <beans:list>
               <beans:value>classpath:info</beans:value>
               <beans:value>classpath:messages</beans:value>
               <beans:value>classpath:labels</beans:value>
               <beans:value>classpath:menu</beans:value>
               <beans:value>classpath:help</beans:value>
            </beans:list>
        </beans:property>
    </beans:bean>

    
    
    <beans:bean id="dataSource"
          class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
            <beans:property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
            <beans:property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://160.1.0.10:3306/DB_REWELT"/>
            <beans:property name="username" value="rewelt"/>
            <beans:property name="password" value="rewelt13"/>  
    </beans:bean>
    <util:list id="hibernateMappingResources">
        <beans:value>com/segurosargos/bitacora/dao/orm/Actividad.hbm.xml</beans:value>
        <beans:value>com/segurosargos/bitacora/dao/orm/ArchivoRespuesta.hbm.xml</beans:value>
        <beans:value>com/segurosargos/bitacora/dao/orm/Asignacion.hbm.xml</beans:value>
        <beans:value>com/segurosargos/bitacora/dao/orm/ColaboradorAsignacion.hbm.xml</beans:value>
        <beans:value>com/segurosargos/bitacora/dao/orm/Grupo.hbm.xml</beans:value>
        <beans:value>com/segurosargos/dao/orm/enum.hbm.xml</beans:value>
        <beans:value>com/segurosargos/dao/orm/direccion.hbm.xml</beans:value>
        <beans:value>com/segurosargos/dao/orm/ciudad.hbm.xml</beans:value>
        <beans:value>com/segurosargos/dao/orm/departamento.hbm.xml</beans:value>
        <beans:value>com/segurosargos/dao/orm/puesto.hbm.xml</beans:value>
        <beans:value>com/segurosargos/dao/orm/ubicacion.hbm.xml</beans:value>
        <beans:value>com/segurosargos/dao/orm/permiso.hbm.xml</beans:value>
        <beans:value>com/segurosargos/dao/orm/colaborador.hbm.xml</beans:value>
        <beans:value>com/segurosargos/dao/orm/fotoColaborador.hbm.xml</beans:value>
        <beans:value>com/segurosargos/dao/orm/ciclo.hbm.xml</beans:value>
        <beans:value>com/segurosargos/dao/orm/conjuntoMetas.hbm.xml</beans:value>
        <beans:value>com/segurosargos/dao/orm/meta.hbm.xml</beans:value>
        <beans:value>com/segurosargos/dao/orm/conjuntoObjetivos.hbm.xml</beans:value>
        <beans:value>com/segurosargos/dao/orm/objetivo.hbm.xml</beans:value>

        
    </util:list>
    <beans:bean id="hibernateProperties" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertiesFactoryBean">
        <beans:property name="properties">
            <beans:props>
                <beans:prop key="hibernate.dialect">${hibernate.dialect}</beans:prop>
                <beans:prop key="hibernate.max_fetch_depth">3</beans:prop>
                <beans:prop key="hibernate.jdbc.fetch_size">100</beans:prop>
                <beans:prop key="hibernate.jdbc.batch_size">10</beans:prop>
                <beans:prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</beans:prop>
                <beans:prop key="hibernate.format_sql">true</beans:prop>
                <beans:prop key="hibernate.default_schema">${database.defaulSchema}</beans:prop>
            </beans:props>
        </beans:property>
    </beans:bean>
    <beans:bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean"
        p:dataSource-ref="dataSource" 
        p:mappingResources-ref="hibernateMappingResources" 
        p:hibernateProperties-ref="hibernateProperties"/>
    
    
    <!--    TRANSACTION MANAGER -->
    <tx:annotation-driven/>
    <beans:bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <beans:qualifier value="transactionManager"/>
        <beans:property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory"/>
    </beans:bean>
    
    
    <!-- SERVICES -->
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.segurosargos.bitacora.service"/>
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.segurosargos.crece.service"/>
    <!-- PERSISTENCE -->
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.segurosargos.bitacora.api"/>
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.segurosargos.crece.api"/>
    <!-- COMPONETS -->
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.segurosargos.util" />


</beans:beans>
```

**EDIT**

GrupoDao is a inteface

```
public interface GrupoDao {


    public void guardar(Grupo grupo);
    

    public Grupo getById(Integer id);
    

    public List<Grupo> getGrupos();
```

This is thier implementation

```
@Repository("GrupoDao")
@Transactional
public class GrupoDaoImpl extends GenericHibernateDaoImpl implements GrupoDao {

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public void guardar(Grupo grupo) {

        this.save(grupo);

    }

    @Override
    @Transactional(readOnly = true)
    public Grupo getById(Integer id) {
        return this.get(Grupo.class, id);

    }

    
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    @Override
    @Transactional(readOnly = true)
    public List<Grupo> getGrupos() {
        String jpql = "FROM Grupo g";
        Query query = getCurrentSession().createQuery(jpql);
        return query.list();
    }
```

}

All works in weblogic, and a few days ago and worked fine, this not change in many days

Comment: Your example code bares no similarity to the stacktrace you have included, so it's impossible to tell what the problem is.  Can you include the code for Test, and the DAO?

Comment: Ok, let me edit the question, but i get same error in all test

Comment: What does your `testEnviromentContext.xml` contain?

Comment: Can you include some of the GrupoDao code?